# How to extract data from only one column in numpy array based on specific value from sorted value of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am sorting an array comprising of two columns in ascending order and then based on value greater than  x in first column, trying to extract data for values > x from 2nd column in another variable.

Able to sort and find the values greater than x in column 1 but not able to extract corresponding values from column for values > x.

```
a1 = np.array([130,4,8,0,87,45,24,22])
a2 = np.array([1.5615, 0.4601, 0.4374, 0.0000, 3.9871, -2.3144, -0.3456, 1.5684])

ind = np.lexsort((a2,a1)) 

[(a1[i],a2[i]) for i in ind]

r = np.array([a1[ind],a2[ind]])
r1 = sorted(x for x in r[0] if x >= 35)
print(r1)
```

expect a3 = [-2.3144   3.9871   1.5615] for values in a2 based on x>35 in a1 [45, 87,130]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accessing the values in `r[0]` you can instead do something like this:

```
>>> sorted([a2[ind] for ind in range(len(a1)) if a1[ind] > 35], key=lambda 
value: np.where(r[1] == value))
[-2.3144, 3.9871, 1.5615]
```

This will check the values at the indices and then sort by where the index is in `r[1]`

Comment: Also figured instead of doing lex sort this can be solved in this way too using your earlier reference `>>> sorted([a2[ind] for ind in range(len(a1)) if a1[ind] > 35], key=lambda value: np.where(a2 == value))`

Comment: @user3412649 you can replace it with `np.nan_to_num(sorted([a2[ind] if a1[ind] > 35 else np.nan for ind in range(len(a1))], key=lambda value: np.where(r[1] == value)))` This will return either `a2[ind]` or `np.nan` if it doesn't exist. Then we can use `np.nan_to_num` to convert `np.nan` values to `0`. Outputs `array([ 1.5615,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -2.3144,  3.9871,  0.    ,
        0.    ])`